# How to get value from input and send it as json object to backend in vue 3

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a questionnaire which shows questions and their answers with vuejs.
django will handle the backend.
I want to get the **question id** and **answer** from the questionnaire and send it to backend as json object.

here is my question component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="section in sections.slice(sectionStart, sectionEnd)" :key="section.id">
        <div v-for="question in section.questions" :key="question.id">
           <!-- Single Choice -->
            <div v-show="question.type === 'Single Choice'" :id="question.id">
                <p class="py-4 font-medium leading-8">{{ question.question_text }}</p>
                <input type="hidden" :value="question.question_text" v-model="question.id">
                <div class="flex py-1" v-for="choice in question.choices" :key="choice.id">
                    <input class="h-5 w-5" type="radio" :name="question.id" v-model="choice.id" :id="choice.id"/>
                    <label class="ml-3" :for="choice.id">{{ choice.text }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple choice -->
            <div v-show="question.type === 'Multiple Choice'" :id="question.id">
                <p class="py-4 font-medium leading-8">{{ question.question_text }}</p>
                <div class="flex py-1" v-for="choice in question.choices" :key="choice.id">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="h-6 w-6" :name="choice.id" :id="choice.id">
                    <label :for="choice.id" class="ml-3">{{ choice.text }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            sections: data.sections,  
        }
    },
    props:[
        'sectionStart',
        'sectionEnd'
    ]
};
</script>
```

**Update 1**

data.sections comes from django:

```
{% block extrahead %}
    {% render_bundle 'index' 'css' %}
    <script> let data = {{ data|safe }};</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and the structure of data:

```
{
   section: [
        0: {
            id: 0,
            desc: "...",
            questions: [
               0: {
                  id: 0,
                  text: "question text....?",
                  choices: [
                      0: {id: 0, text: "choice 1"},
                      1: {id: 1, text: "choice 2"},
                      2: {...}
                  ]
               },
               1: {...},
            ]
        },
       1: {...},
       2: {...}
   ]
}
```

**Update 2**

the json format I want to have:

```
responses: {
   question_id: response_id,
}
```

***How can I get question id and it's answer and save these value to json object and then send it to backend?***

Comment: Where does `data.sections` come from? There are no `data` as props and you are not using `this` keyword as well

Comment: data.sections comes from backend as json object, which contains questions and their answers

Comment: @MahdiJafari Where is `data.sections` injected to this component? And what is the structure of it?

Comment: @StevenSiebert, I updated the question based on your question. can you help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set up your `v-model`. Currently you refer to things like `v-model="choice.id"` which aren't existing in your data properties. How the structure of your `v-model` needs to be depends on how you want to pass the data.

As an example you could pass it like you already tried, with `v-model`. But instead of `v-model="choice.id"` we use `v-model="userAnswers[section.id][question.id][choice.id]"` after creating it in our data properties:

```
data() {
        return {
            sections: data.sections,
            userAnswers: {}
        }
    }
```

So using `userAnswers[section.id][question.id][choice.id]` will generate something like this:

```
{
  0: { // First section
    0: { // First question
      0: false, // Choices with true or false 
      1: true,
      2: false,
      3: false
    }
  },
  1: {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Usage with the provided structure

So you provided the following structure:

```
responses: {
   question_id: response_id,
}
```

This is only possible for questions with only one answer and only if every answer has an unique `id` outside of their section. If the first question of a section always has `0` as their `id`, that won't work. But if they have, thatn it is simply this: `userAnswers[question.id]` as `v-model` of the radio buttons while they to provide the `response_id` as their values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I get the basics idea. this userAnswers[section.id][question.id][choice.id]  throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

Comment: You mean the posted example object? That is not for usage, as `1: { ... }` will throw this error.

Comment: I updated the answer format I want, can you help?

Comment: @MahdiJafari Edited my answer with an approach to your needed structure. This would be the base for your further work. If this helped you, don´t hesitate to vote. Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me more? I changed like this: v-model="this.responses[question.id, choice.id]".  but the last option of single choice question is always checked, also it don't save question_id and choice_id to responses.

Comment: In `v-model` you don't use `this`, it should be just `v-model="responses[question.id, choice.id]"`. And `responses[question.id, choice.id]` wouldn't generate what you requested. You should use `responses[question.id]`, the `choice.id` would be applied automatically, when selected, if it is the `value` of the option.

Comment: I did as your instructions. but when i check one, all checkbox become checked, also the last option of single choice question is always checked. can you help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236847/discussion-between-mahdi-jafari-and-stevensiebert).